# Match 1, 2, or 3 digit number between two slashes

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm reading a URL string that holds year and pagination page. They come in two variations:

`/news/2016/2` and `/news/2/2016`

The smaller number is the pagination number and it should never be bigger than 3 digits. The 4 digit number is the year.

I'm able to match the year: `/\d{4}/` and the pagination 3 digit limit, however I can't make it force the starting forward slash. I tried these two solutions:

`[1-9]?\d(?=\/|$)` - it will match 1 through 3 digit number, but it ignores the starting slash, so the year will match as well.

`(?=\/)[1-9]?\d(?=\/|$)` - the way the documentation explains it, but it doesn't match anything...

P.S. This is for javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regex with a capturing group and a word boundary:

```
\/(\d{1,3})\b
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fE2wI5/1)

It will capture 1 to 3 digits after a `/`. The word boundary will not let a match within 4+-digit numbers.

```js
var re = /\/(\d{1,3})\b/; 
var str = '/news/2016/2';
var res = str.match(re);
if (res) {
  document.getElementById("r").innerHTML = res[1];
}
```

```html
<div id="r"/>
```

Comment: It does return the 1 through 3 digit number, but it also returns the leading forward slash. I know can remove that with res[1].substr(1), however I'd like to avoid that if possible. So the question is, is it possible to return (match) the number without the leading forward slash? Thanks!

Comment: `res[1]` contains the captured text, without the slash. Lookbehinds are not supported in JavaScript, thus, you cannot just match the number without the slash - capturing is meant to be used in such cases.

Comment: Just FYI: even if JS supported a lookbehind, a lookaround solution would be less efficient. I'd go with the same approach in .NET, PHP, etc, *unless*  you do not have access to the full spectrum of the language features (which is usually the case when using regexps in some applications taking only regex and returning only matched values).